# New Python 3. mySQL install user access denied

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I have just installed mySQL on my Mac. The install appears to have been successful. I can successfully start and stop mySQL from the terminal command line. While in python I am attempting to create a connection and a cursor but am getting the following error message:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

My code to get to this point is very simple:

```
import mysql.connector
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user = 'root')
```

the import statement executes without error but the command to create the connection gives the previously stated error. I have gone through all the internet questions I could find about this topic and none of them had a solution for me. Could this be a password issue. When I installed SQL I was given a password that during the SQL install process I was told I would be prompted for but I have not been prompted for the password. I tried to include the password as part of the connection configure parameters but that just gave the following error message:

```
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user = 'root', password = 'supplied_pass')
mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 1862 (HY000): Your password has expired. To log in you must change it using a client that supports expired passwords.
```

Any help on solving this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. After the SQL install it was necessary to perform a secure installation where I reset the password and eliminated the anonymous user. The password reset and anonymous user elimination occurred by following the prompts from the secure install. The original install was in the /usr/local/mysql/ directory. So at the terminal prompt I did a change directory to the /usr/local/mysql/ directory (cd /usr/local/mysql/bin/). Once in the new directory I typed this command at the terminal prompt: sudo ./mysql_secure_installation . At that point I just followed all the prompts to change the password and eliminate the anonymous user. Once that was complete I was able to successfully create a SQL connection and cursor.